# Batch command to overlay 2 PNGs on top of each other

Tags: image, batch-file, graphics, imagemagick, png

I am in the process of finalizing the creation of graphics and try to automate the overlaying of two PNGs (which have the same size).

I have 2 folders with fixed directories, for example let's say *"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Backrounds"* and *"C:\Users\User\Desktop\Overlays"*.

The files in "*Overlays*" are named as follows: *"ID-RandomNumber-Backround.png"*. The variable "*Backround*" can be "*Blue*", "*Red*" or "*Yellow*".

The files in the "*Backrounds*" folder are the future backgrounds - named (you almost guessed it): "*Blue.png*", "*Red.png*" and "*Yellow.png*".

My goal at the moment is to write a script, which automates ALL files from the folder Overlays with the corresponding backgrounds (depending on the file name) from the folder Backrounds to provide - so the PNGs in the right order to put on top of each other. So the file "001-2812-Blue.png" should get the background named"Blue.png", the file "002-2612-Yellow.png" should get the background named "Yellow.png" and so on.

I'm using Windows 10 and have thought of a batch script that does this work via imagemagick and composite. Unfortunately, I am currently somehow completely lost, what a possible script could look like. Probably I'm just standing on the hose.

I would be infinitely grateful if you could give me a hint how a possible script could look like. Thank you!
If you have any questions or need more information, just let me know!

---

To make it a little bit clearer what exactly I have in mind, you can find a little graphic enclosed that shows what I have in mind - maybe it helps a little bit :)

[image]

Comment: May be this will help you? https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/jscript/imageProcessing/stamp.bat

Comment: Command line like this: `for /r "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Overlays" %i in (*-Blue.png) do "c:\program\ImageMagick\convert.exe" -composite -gravity center "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Backrounds\Blue.png" "%~i" "%~dpni_NewFile.png"`